# stored proc for update record using case or if else condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have table I want to write sp for update according to user id I written condition I want to use if else or case condition in sp ...how I will write ?

```
table:    
    SELECT [ConId], [User_Id], [UserName], [UserStatus], [ContUser_Id], 
    [ContUserName], [ContUserStatus], [ContBlock], [ContDelete], [Active], [Date] 
    FROM   [dbo].[bb_Contact] 

sp:

    CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_UpdateContactId] 
    @ContId int, @UserId int
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN  

    if(@UserId = [User_Id])
    {
        update [bb_Contact]
        set [UserStatus]=1,
        where [ConId]= @ContId
    }
    else if(@UserId=[ContUser_Id])
    {
        update [bb_Contact]
        set [ContUser_Id]=1
        where [ConId]= @ContId
    }

    COMMIT
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_UpdateContactId] 
@ContId int, @UserId int
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN  

if exists
(select * 
 from [bb_Contact] 
 where [ConId]= @ContId 
       and @UserId = [User_Id])
    update [bb_Contact]
    set [UserStatus]=1
    where [ConId]= @ContId
    and @UserId = [User_Id]
else
    update [bb_Contact]
    set [ContUser_Id]=1
    where [ConId]= @ContId
    and @UserId=[ContUser_Id]

COMMIT
```